# IIS IP Address and Domain Restrictions (Block All Allow One)

Tags: iis, ip

I would like to block all IP addresses from connecting to my server except for only **one** specific IP. How can I do this?

I tried the following below as seen in my image, but if I connect via a VPS which has the specific IP I want to be allowed (IE: 1.2.3.4), it's still blocking me.

The reason I want do block all IP's is because I only want one permitted server to connect to my second server to execute a PHP script. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Verify the IP address of the server you are trying to connect to. The server may be assigned multiple IP addresses, so make sure you are using the correct one. Also, check the server logs for any error messages or related information about the connection being blocked.